# soft deleting mongoid document along with associated documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, soft-delete

I have 2 models, user and posts

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paranoia
  references_many :posts, :autosave => true, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  referenced_in :user
end
```

Now when I soft delete user, I also want to soft delete posts. Is there any way I can do this?

For soft deleting a document I am using [Mongoid::Paranoia](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Paranoia)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to delete the users posts? If I was following some thread (I assume that the posts are threaded), and some user, who wrote some posts in the threads, deleted his profile, I wouldn't like his posts to be removed. This would break the flow of the post-thread.

I'm aware that this doesn't answer your question, but it might be grounds for considering if you really *need* to delete the posts.

Answer (score 0):

Would a before_destroy callback do what you need? e.g.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paranoia
  references_many :posts, :autosave => true, :dependent => :destroy
  before_destroy :delete_posts

  def delete_posts
    posts.delete_all
  end
end

class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paranoia
  referenced_in :user
end
```

Comment: I did that also but this solution seems like a bit hack to me. I was thinking of whether paranoia would include something like this. Also, posts.delete_all will do hard delete, I would have to loop through posts and delete them individually.

Comment: I agree its not all that elegant. It is a bit strange that callbacks get invoked but cascade rules don't. There is a related open issue at https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/857 so it may change in the future. There is a different solution suggested there - before_destroy :cascade! which might be a little less hacky.

Comment: I tried cascade also but it is only destroying post but what if post references_many :comments? in that case it is not deleting comments.